# Apollo client + graphql + api-platform error after query execution

Tags: symfony, graphql, apollo-client, api-platform.com

In my api-platform app with a graphql endpoint I make the following mutation to server

```
export const UPDATE_ITEM_MUTATION = function () {
  return gql`
  mutation($id:ID!,$nombre:String!,$codigoReeup: String,$categoria: String,$organismo: String,$abreviatura:String,$descripcion:String,$observaciones:Iterable,
    $domicilioLegal:String,$clientMutationId: String!,$telefonos:Iterable,$emails:Iterable,$sitioWeb:String)
    {
      updateCliente(  
        input:{
          id: $id,nombre: $nombre,codigoReeup:$codigoReeup,categoria:$categoria,abreviatura:$abreviatura,descripcion:$descripcion,organismo:$organismo,
          observaciones:$observaciones,domicilioLegal:$domicilioLegal,
          clientMutationId:$clientMutationId,telefonos:$telefonos,emails:$emails,sitioWeb:$sitioWeb
        })
         {
          id,nombre,abreviatura,codigoReeup,descripcion,observaciones,ultimaDocEntregadaAt,domicilioLegal,organismo{denominacion},
          categoria{denominacion},telefonos,emails,sitioWeb
         }
    }`
}
```

after the mutation success I'm return to the client list page and then this query is executed:

```
`
  { clientes(order:${order})
    { edges
      { 
        node
          { 
            id,nombre,abreviatura,codigoReeup,descripcion,observaciones,ultimaDocEntregadaAt,domicilioLegal,telefonos,emails,sitioWeb,
            organismo{denominacion},categoria{denominacion}
          } 
      } 
    } 
  }`
```

after the server 200 code response with the espected updated apollo throws this error stack

Updated: Added the error

```
Error: "Network error: Error writing result to store for query: {"kind":"Document","definitions":[{"kind":"OperationDefinition","operation":"query","variableDefinitions":[],"directives":[],"selectionSet":{"kind":"SelectionSet","selections":[{"kind":"Field","name":{"kind":"Name","value":"clientes"},"arguments":[{"kind":"Argument","name":{"kind":"Name","value":"order"},"value":{"kind":"ObjectValue","fields":[{"kind":"ObjectField","name":{"kind":"Name","value":"nombre"},"value":{"kind":"StringValue","value":"ASC","block":false}}]}}],"directives":[],"selectionSet":{"kind":"SelectionSet","selections":[{"kind":"Field","name":{"kind":"Name","value":"edges"},"arguments":[],"directives":[],"selectionSet":{"kind":"SelectionSet","selections":[{"kind":"Field","name":{"kind":"Name","value":"node"},"arguments":[],"directives":[],"selectionSet":{"kind":"SelectionSet","selections":[{"kind":"Field","name":{"kind":"Name","value":"id"},"arguments":[],"directives":[]},{"kind":"Field","name":{"kind":"Name","value":"nombre"},"arguments":[],"directives":[]},{"kind":"Field","name":{"kind":"Name","value":"abreviatura"},"arguments":[],"directives":[]},{"kind":"Field","name":{"kind":"Name","value":"codigoReeup"},"arguments":[],"directives":[]},{"kind":"Field","name":{"kind":"Name","value":"descripcion"},"arguments":[],"directives":[]},{"kind":"Field","name":{"kind":"Name","value":"observaciones"},"arguments":[],"directives":[]},{"kind":"Field","name":{"kind":"Name","value":"ultimaDocEntregadaAt"},"arguments":[],"directives":[]},{"kind":"Field","name":{"kind":"Name","value":"domicilioLegal"},"arguments":[],"directives":[]},{"kind":"Field","name":{"kind":"Name","value":"telefonos"},"arguments":[],"directives":[]},{"kind":"Field","name":{"kind":"Name","value":"emails"},"arguments":[],"directives":[]},{"kind":"Field","name":{"kind":"Name","value":"sitioWeb"},"arguments":[],"directives":[]},{"kind":"Field","name":{"kind":"Name","value":"organismo"},"arguments":[],"directives":[],"selectionSet":{"kind":"SelectionSet","selections":[{"kind":"Field","name":{"kind":"Name","value":"denominacion"},"arguments":[],"directives":[]},{"kind":"Field","name":{"kind":"Name","value":"__typename"}}]}},{"kind":"Field","name":{"kind":"Name","value":"categoria"},"arguments":[],"directives":[],"selectionSet":{"kind":"SelectionSet","selections":[{"kind":"Field","name":{"kind":"Name","value":"denominacion"},"arguments":[],"directives":[]},{"kind":"Field","name":{"kind":"Name","value":"__typename"}}]}},{"kind":"Field","name":{"kind":"Name","value":"__typename"}}]}},{"kind":"Field","name":{"kind":"Name","value":"__typename"}}]}},{"kind":"Field","name":{"kind":"Name","value":"__typename"}}]}}]}}],"loc":{"start":0,"end":310}} 

Store error: the application attempted to write an object with no provided id but the store already contains an id of Organismo:/api/organismos/50b4a4b2-638d-486e-80e0-bab276a722e5 for this object. The selectionSet that was trying to be written is: {"kind":"Field","name":{"kind":"Name","value":"organismo"},"arguments":[],"directives":[],"selectionSet":{"kind":"SelectionSet","selections":[{"kind":"Field","name":{"kind":"Name","value":"denominacion"},"arguments":[],"directives":[]},{"kind":"Field","name":{"kind":"Name","value":"__typename"}}]}}"
```

It seem to be a writing error in its own cache

Any tip, after this nothing works

Thanks in advance

Note: I'm not doing any other query to request for that organismo entity

Comment: "this error stack"... what error stack? :) Please update your question to include the error you are seeing

Comment: updated, sorry for the mistakes. As you can see it seems to be a failed attempt to write its own cache but I don't know why. In case of create I follow the same workflow and this is not happening. Only happens on update

Comment: Hmm. If you look at the server response in the network tab, do you see the server actually returning a value for `id`? Also, is your InMemoryCache instance configured with a custom `dataIdFromObject` function or `addTypename` set to `false`?

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't adding the id field when requesting for nested objects and neither specified the dataIdFromObject. So apollo fallsback to default dataIdFromObject and at some point I made a request for the organismo object for a select options and when I request again for list it crashes.

Comment: Do you have any error in your server logs?

Comment: No, there are no errors from server. Also the update process is successfull, the workflow failed at client when apollo was trying to add the response object to its cache. Already solved with @DanielRearden's recomendation